# Color Configuration 3x3 board

Tags: board-games

I came across this question in FB. I tried to solve but unable to get the answer for it. Feeling so demotivated. This is the question:

I need to turn the whole board WHITE.
 Rules of the game:
1.When you select a square, the color of that square switches (from Black to White or vice-versa).
2.In the same move, the colors of the squares at the TOP, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTTOM of the selected square, if available on the board, switch (from Black to White or vice-versa) as well.
Which squares should I select to win the game.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that question doesn't say *to turn all the written numbers white*.. :D

Comment: It says to turn the board white! It should be covered full of white

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This kind of puzzle is commonly referred to as "lights out", after a board game by that name.  I googled that phrase and came upon a solver at http://www.ueda.info.waseda.ac.jp/~n-kato/lightsout/.  So I can't take credit for the answer but it's pretty simple:

> 1, 3, 7, 9

Answer (score 1):

The answer to that puzzle is the following moves:

1. First select the square number 5 to turn all the board to black.
2. Then select all the squares positionned in a corner which are 1, 3, 7 and 9. We obtain like that the inverse of the initial board.
3. Then simply select the square number 5 and all the board is white.

Comment: But the 5 in step 1 and 3 cancel eachother out, so you don't need to select 5 in this set up.